# Modx [revolution 2.3.5] login snippet, users are not getting sessions after logging in.

Tags: php, session, cookies, modx

I'm having a strange issue with a new modx site - web users are not getting sessions after logging in.  I'm sure they are authenticating correctly but modx does not seem to be setting the session. I think it has something to do with context access.

I have 3 contexts, web, French & English I have user groups and resource groups which has access to the appropriate contexts.

here is my login snippett:

```
[[!Login? 
     &loginTpl=`LoginTpl`  
     &logoutTpl=`LogoutTpl`  
     &errTpl=`lgnErrTpl`  
     &loginResourceId=`91`
     &logoutResourceId=`5` 
     &contexts=`English,French`
     ]]
```

users are not being granted access to the web resource as it will be used for internal documentation.

NOW, everything appears to behave normally, if you enter incorrect credentials in the login form, you get a login error. If you enter correct credentials you get forwarded to the correct resource [91] BUT the user does not have a session [[!+modx.user.id]] returns 0 for the anonymous user. 
AND if I look at my browser cookies, all I have is the default php session cookie and no modx session cookies.  curiously, the cookie path is /docs/ which is the base_url for the web context. if I change the cookie path to / in modx then all pages are blank for the user!!

What is causing the problem here??

Answer (score 0):

try to add this at the top of the page,

```
$sessid = session_id();
    if(empty($sessid)) {
        session_start();
        $sessid = session_id();
    }
```

Comment: We already know we have a PHP session because we are reading the cookie.  This won't do anything with modx session cookies.